# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused - MAMP & Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

I've a problem with symfony.
When I try to run this command :

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

And I've error:

```
[PDOException]                             
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

Here is my config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        unix_socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

And my parameters.yml

```
parameters: 
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: '8889'
    database_name: sil19
    database_user: root
    database_password: root
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: e7f97888e382ddd2e235dc7da6fc39346b37096c
    database_path: null
```

I don't know where the problem is from. So if someone have any idea. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the Mysql service is running on your server, ie are you able to access the database via command line or a simple database connect php page.

Comment: I've find the solution. Thanks you for your help

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'had to check "Allow network access to Mysql" to make it work on MAMP.

Comment: Where did you check it?

Comment: @shredding : In the Mysql tab. It was for the old interface I don't know where the checkbox is on the new one

Comment: Same problem and checking "Allow network access to MySQL" solved it! +1

Answer (score 4):

I'have got the same error when trying to connect SYMFONY 4 to MAMP Mysql:

```
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

For my case, it was a wrong Mysql port, just changed 3306 to 8889 to fix it

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:8889/db_name
```

in my .env file

Comment: This is the exact issue for me and it worked once I changed the port to 8889. +1

Answer (score 0):

Run at the full path, like this:

`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/php bin/console`

Answer (score 0):

On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL programs attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file. This occurs even if a --port or -P option is given to specify a port number. To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the local server, use --host or -h to specify a host name value of 127.0.0.1, or the IP address or name of the local server. You can also specify the connection protocol explicitly, even for localhost, by using the
https://blog.liplex.de/symfony-console-connection-refused-with-mamp/